# В блоге django не ищет посты с русским заголовком и не меняет содержимое поста на русском языке

Tags: django

Написал блог, смотря видеокурс на ютубе. Однако есть проблемы с использованием русского языка на сайте. В поиске ввожу название поста на русском с нижним регистром и по идее он должен искать любые совпадения независимо от регистра букв, но это не работает только с русским языком.
Вот код:

```
def posts_list(request):
search_query = request.GET.get('search', '')

if search_query:
    posts = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_query) | Q(body__icontains=search_query))
else:
    posts = Post.objects.all()
```

HTML форма:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action='{% url "posts_list" %}'>
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" name='search'>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```

И еще, посты на русском языке создаются, но их нельзя изменять. Выводится такое сообщение: "Значение должно состоять только из букв, цифр, знаков подчеркивания или дефиса.".

Comment: По поводу поиска, не используйте `sqlite`

Comment: Перевел на postgresql поиск начал работать, спасибо!